# Wordpress Database & WP Migrate

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, migrate

I built a WordPress website in localhost MAMP. Upon completing the site, I wanted to upload it to the actual hosting site using FTP. I uploaded all the content but DB. I used a WordPress plugin called 'WP Migrate' to export the database. Then I uploaded exported file to phpMyAdmin.
But the site did not work after uploading onto my site using FTP. I then begin to work again locally, using my local host. There is a feature to find & replace DB values in 'WP Migrate'. I replaced existing local site name with actual web site name. This stopped working my local website also. 
I am not trying to figure the live site, but figure the local host site right now, that way I can perform a transfer. I believe it has to do with the DB somehow but not sure where or how to edit it.

Basically it is the same issue that this person is having as well, but the question wasn't answered: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/undo-find-replace/

Nathan Rojas

Comment: The db name and user probably weren't the same. What did you 'find and replace?'

Comment: I honestly do not remember I think I put the website under replace

Comment: You need to update the Wp database user and password to conform to the one you created in wp-config

Comment: would I update that in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: also where would I find it to update it? I don't really know much about databases at all nor editing

Answer (score 0):

If it's after you updated your site name, you can easily change it back by logging into the myPhpAdmin of your local site and choosing the MySQL database you are using. under the wp_options table, you'll see a field called `siteurl` and `home`. Update those fields to what you had prior and it'll come back. ;)

[image]

Comment: Then that is a separate issue from duplicator. You mentioned that you upload the new install and such, and I'm not sure why you'd upload the file to the already-installed wp install. Can you provide more info so I can edit my answer?

Comment: If you want to change the site name back, you can look under wp_options in the database in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I checked the file and the names are the same as what they were before

Comment: Basically this is what happened but no one has answered their problem with it either. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/undo-find-replace/

Comment: So you probably made a mistake spelling or trailing slashes.

Comment: I don't think I did. I'm just not sure what happened when I initiated the task, Find & Replace. It's still broke.